# Xcode 8 constraint help required

Tags: ios, autolayout, xcode8

[image: xcode design]

I am new to IOS development and have the attached screen that I am developing in portrait mode only. I have fiddled around with constraints for half of today but not really got anywhere with making this work on anything other than a 5s.

Not sure if i constrain to edge of phone and/or the box at the side of the one i am trying to constrain or both!

It would be much appreciated if someone could point me in the right direction to get this to fit on all screen sizes. Landscape I think is a pipe dream at this stage:)

Comment: Maybe you can describe your view hierarchy a bit more. Are those collection views? Are you using stack views? etc.

Comment: What does it look like when it is on a device that breaks the layout?

Comment: the various buttons are just subject headings that display another view controller when pressed. I am not using stack views as i don't fully understand them and just trying to keep it simple. When i resize to an iPhone 6 or 7 the boxes stay adjusted to the left side of the screen as you look at it. not sure how to add another image to the message string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the width constraints you should add to each button:

- add a equal widths constraint for each button to the main view, then set it's multiplier to 0.5. That will make each button half the width of the screen.
- for the dark blue buttons, make a leading constraint to the left edge of the view (not the margin) and set it's constant to 0.
- for the light blue buttons, make a trailing constraint to the right edge of the view (not the margin) and set it's constant to 0.

For the Y positioning, you should do the following:

- for the top buttons, add a vertical spacing constraint from the buttons to the title view, with the constant set to whatever you want
- for each button that follows underneath, add a vertical spacing constraint to the button above it with a constant of 0
- for the bottom buttons, and a vertical spacing constraint to the bottom layout guide with a constant of 0

This will adjust the height of the buttons to match the screen size / orientation while maintaining your layout. should work fine with landscape, although those buttons will be awfully skinny!

Comment: Thank you. Works a treat. Might get to watch some telly tonight now!

Comment: my pleasure...don't forget to mark it as the correct answer, please.

Comment: Is it ok to ask another question pertaining to the original or do i need to create a new post?

Comment: best to create a new question if you can't find the answer